# Why is my form calling the wrong Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

The flow of my app is as follows: A file is submitted on the transcribe.html page first which then redirects to the  transcibe-complete.html page where the user can click to beginning transcription.

Why is the 'transcribeSubmit' view being called instead of the 'initiate_transcription' view when the user clicks the 'click to transcribe' button on the 'initiate_transcription' page?

Each page has their own JS file to ensure that forms are submitted separately.

html:
(transcribe.html):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'transcribeSubmit' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="transcribe-file" class="transcribe-file-label">Choose audio/video file</label>
    <input id="transcribe-file" name="file" type="file" accept="audio/*, video/*" hidden>
    <button class="upload" id="transcribe-submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

(transcribe-complete):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'initiate_transcription' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="output-lang--select-summary"></label>
    <select class="output-lang-select" id="output-lang--select-summary" name="audio_language">
                        <option value="detect">Detect language</option>
                        <option value="zh">Chinese</option>
                        <option value="en">English</option>
                        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
                        <option value="de">German</option>
                        <option value="jp">Japanese</option>
                        <option value="ko">Korean</option>
                        <option value="ru">Russian</option>
                        <option value="pt">Portugese</option>
                    </select>
                </div>    
                <div class="transcribe-output"> 
    <button id="transcribe-button" type="submit">Click to Transcribe</button>
</div> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addeventlistener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventdefault();

        const formdata = new formdata(form);
        const xhr = new xmlhttprequest();

        xhr.open('post', form.getattribute('action'), true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            console.log("ready state: ", xhr.readystate);
            console.log("status: ", xhr.status);
        }
        xhr.responsetype = 'blob';
        xhr.send(formdata);
    });
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            request.session['uploaded_file_name'] = filename
            request.session['uploaded_file_path'] = fs.path(filename)
            
            #transcribe_file(uploaded_file)
            #return redirect(reverse('proofreadFile'))
            return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete.html', {"form": form})
        else:
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe.html', {"form": form})

@csrf_protect
def initiate_transcription(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the file's name and path from the session
        file_name = request.session.get('uploaded_file_name')
        file_path = request.session.get('uploaded_file_path')
        if file_name and file_path:
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                transcribe_file(file_name, f)
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error': 'No file uploaded'})
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error': 'Invalid request'})
```

transcribe/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.transcribeSubmit, name = "transcribeSubmit"),
path("", views.initiate_transcription, name = "initiate_transcription"),
]
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from translator import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),#redirects to translator/
    path('translator/', include('translator.urls')),
    path('translator/translator_upload/', include('translator_upload.urls')),
    path('proofreader/', include('proofreader.urls')),
    path('proofreader/proofreader_upload/', include('proofreader_upload.urls')),
    path('transcribe/', include('transcribe.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Update the question with the url paths.

Comment: please also share the urls.py file to check the name of the action URL.

Comment: @McPherson Hi, I updated it.

Comment: @RajpurohitDhanpalSingh Hi, I updated it.

Comment: Inside transcribeSubmit you have an empty `else` Let's get rid of that first :)

Comment: @S.D. I added it when testing my views and didn;t remove completely when posting to SO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your url patterns. You are matching two empty paths to two different views. Django will simply match the first path, and call its view. You need to give each one different path names.

```
urlpatterns = [
path("transcribe/", views.transcribeSubmit, name = "transcribeSubmit"),
path("init-transcription/", views.initiate_transcription, name = "initiate_transcription"),
]
```

Comment: It works thanks.